# error while using distrubuted array in julia

Tags: julia, distributed-computing

I am learning parallel computation for this 
 want to use distributed array in julia, but I am facing some error while using its library

> ERROR: ArgumentError: DistributedArrays not found in path

I am using ubuntu 14.04 and julia version 0.4.2

Please help me to resolve this problem

Comment: Did you add it? `Pkg.add("DistributedArrays")`

Comment: https://github.com/JuliaParallel/DistributedArrays.jl

Comment: http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/manual/packages/

Comment: No I haven't added it .. let me add it .. thanks for the quick reply .

Comment: yes its working  now .. I am beginner .. thanks a lot ...

Comment: @Reza Afzalan you could move your comment to an answer, it could also be improved explaining that DataFrames was moved out to a package in order for amit to be able to mark this as solved. This things should be in [NEWS.md](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/NEWS.md)

Answer (score 2):

> DArrays have been removed from Julia Base library in v0.4

`Pkg.add("DistributedArrays")` # => it must be added

> so it is now necessary to import the DistributedArrays package on all spawned processes.

`@everywhere using DistributedArrays`